# Could not find gem 'vagrant-triggers;vagrant (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine

Tags: windows-7, vagrant

Encountering this issue using Vagrant on Windows 7. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got similar error under window10 during a '***vagrant up***' command execution
after a '***vagrant init joomlatools/box***'

By checking folder *%Vagrand install folder%\embedded\gems\gems* (for my installation this is *C:\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems*) there were no vagrant-triggers subfolder inside.

So I just forced installtion of that plugin manually through command:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
```

It installs the plugin,

Then you can issue again a 'vangrant up' that hopefully will not bug !