# Unable to install vagrant-hostupdater plugin during Vagrant up with VVV

Tags: vagrant, vvv-wordpress

I'm new to Vagrant and my aim is to install Varying Vagrant Vagrants. I was following the steps mentioned in [VVV's GitHub page](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV#the-first-vagrant-up) but I'm stuck up when installing [vagrant-hostupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater) mentioned in step 4.

I'm getting the following error when I tried to install the vagrant-hostupdater plugin.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Daniel>vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostupdater
Installing the 'vagrant-hostupdater' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

Could not find gem 'vagrant-hostupdater (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem so
urces listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more tha
n once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpect
ed gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come
 from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle con
fig disable_multisource true`.
```

I'm running **Windows 8.1 64-bit OS** and I installed **Virtual Box 5.0** and **Vagrant 1.8.1**

Has anyone encountered the above issue?

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595579/could-not-find-gem-vagrant-triggersvagrant-0-x86-mingw32-in-any-of-the-g) similar to mine, in stackoverflow. Will the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33636318/5569979) mentioned in the specified similar question help in fixing mine?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have tried it and seen the github page you have shared.
Well, in your case you are making a typo i.e. spelling error:
its **not** '**vagrant-hostupdater**', it's called the '**vagrant-hostsupdater**' package, you are missing an '*s*' in there.

Here is the *github* page hosting the vagrant-hostsupdater code:
https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the typo. It worked and thank you so much.

Comment: OMG I did same thing and same typo :) thanks Maria :)

Comment: Totally had the exact same problem. It's hostSupdater!! Glad that's resolved! Thanks so much for your answer!